# How can I hide a table until filtered/input entered in search

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter, html-table

I'm new to web developing but catching on fairly quickly. I'm developing a wiki page for my company and I have a filter table built but I want to hide the table until the filter function is applied when a user enters their search text. So this way it only shows the text input box and then when they type in their search the table results will THEN show.

I'm using this Javascript for the filtering:

```
  function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

      }
    }
  }
}
```

on a basic search table with this html code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput"            onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" placeholder="Search for           names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
```

....and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
 
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

      }
    }
  }
  
   var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');
   
   if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" placeholder="Search for           names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 2</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 3</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
```

This seems to do the trick! On the load of the window, it loops through all the table rows which do now have the class of header. So your header, is always visible.

Then as your code originally did, it goes through the table and filters out the ones that are matching.

After this, I just added in another loop which then sets the rows back to display: none if there is nothing that is in the input box.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I like this idea - im not sure I'm doing it correctly though as it doesn't seem to change anything - maybe it's because im using a wiki net page so I'm only able to create within a portion of the page so it won't allow these kinds of page load commands? Like I said, I'm pretty new so I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: Is the window on load function supposed to be a separate java script at the top of the my page code?

Comment: No that will all fit into one script tag at the bottom of the page

Comment: (Thank you for helping me btw) so I made a dummy page with just this code to make sure nothing else is Messing it up and I still can't seem to get it to work - the wiki page is giving me an error every time I try to save it. Honestly I think it might not like the page loading command - the page is setup with its own wikinet headers and footers - I wouldn't think it should effect my table but when I take that command out, it loads up fine. :-/

Comment: What's actually happening with that onload function being defined? Is it producinf an error? What does the screen look like

Comment: now it's rejecting any edit I make on any page. I think this is a wikinet system problem now - I'll come back to this in a bit and troubleshoot again - will let you know.

Comment: Okay let me know so I can help!

Answer (score 0):

You could give the table default styles that hide it so when it renders, its default state will be hidden.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable" style="display:none;">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>contact</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I did try that with the display style set to none but then the table is hidden but it will not show any results when the user enters their search - so I need a way for the results to be visible once it's filtered.

Comment: In the callback, instead of making the display attribute an empty string, make it `block`.

Comment: Okay / I'm trying this one again- I have my table style set to display none - so when I open the page the table is hidden but nothing is visible when I do the key up in the box. Where would I set the display attribute to block in order to negate the table none display for keyup?

Comment: In `ContactsearchFX`, change `tr[i].style.display = "";` to `tr[i].style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the `ContactsearchFX` function on page load:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ContactsearchFX);
```

... and requiring that `filter` is not the empty string in the condition for displaying a row.

This has one particular advantage: some browsers remember the last text that was entered in the input box, and fill that text automatically again on page load. With this solution, the corresponding table rows will be filtered immediately.

For a more responsive effect, I would remove the `onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()"` HTML attribute, and instead add the following JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', ContactsearchFX);
});
```

Also consider using the [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) and `cells` collections instead of `getElementsByTagName`

Probably you want to keep the header row out of the filtering process, and so your loop should start at 1 instead of 0.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ContactsearchFX();
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', ContactsearchFX);
});

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;     
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.rows;
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].cells[0];
    if (td) {
      tr[i].style.display = filter && td.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
        ? "" : "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for           names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 2</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test 3</td>
    <td>number</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```